# The best Xpath option for the below example

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Please let me know the best xpath for the below HTML, the button id's are dynamically populated. Hence I tried using the starts-with function as below

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("*//button[starts-with(@id, 'j_idt')]")).click();
```

but, how to achieve if we have two buttons in the same page as per the attached screenshot.

[image: Application page and its HTML souce code]

Comment: Please include the sample html code as text - typing it of the screen to reproduce your issue is tedious and error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to find the button. One of the options is to rely on the text inside, e.g. for `Login`:

```
//button[span = 'Login']
```

Then, you can add other checks, e.g. check if it is of type `submit`:

```
//button[@type = 'submit' and span = 'Login']
```

Comment: You don't need the `text()`. Conversion to an atomic value is done automatically.

Comment: @dirkk I have a scenario where there are 3 "Save" buttons available in the same page, how to define the xpath in this scenario.

Comment: Well, if they have everything in common (same text, no ID or similar even for a parent element to distinguish them) you could use the position, e.g. `(//button[span = 'Save'])[1]` would get you the first button. However, this is a new question, so if this doesn't already solve it for you please ask a new question with all the necessary details.